# Proving the uncertainty relation for the quantum covariance matrix

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, heisenberg-uncertainty-principle, quantum-optics, linear-algebra

In quantum optics papers we often encounter this version of the Heisenberg uncertainly relation (for an $n$-mode quantum system):

$\sigma + \iota \Omega \ge 0$

Where $\sigma$ is the covariance matrix $\sigma = \operatorname{Tr}(\hat \rho \{\hat{\textbf{r}}, \hat{\textbf{r}}^T  \} )$ and $\hat{\textbf{r}} = (\hat x_1, \hat p_1, ...,\hat x_n, \hat p_n)^T$ contains the quadrature operators, where the curly brackets represent the anticommutator, e.g. $\sigma_{12} = \operatorname{Tr}(\hat \rho(\hat x_1\hat p_1 + \hat p_1 \hat x_1))$, $\sigma_{23} = \operatorname{Tr}(\hat \rho(\hat p_1\hat x_2 + \hat x_2 \hat p_1))$

$\Omega = \bigoplus \limits_{j=1}^n \omega_j$

with $\omega_j = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ -1 & 0\end{bmatrix}$

Is there a simple way to prove this relation?

Comment: Try first to do it for just one pair of quadrature operators

Comment: What is $\{r,r^T\}$?

Comment: @JasonFunderberker I edited the question